# Tkinter set new value for labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I set a new value to a label in tkinter?
I have this code, but it's only show a blank window
Sorry for my english and, please, if you can, explain. (I'm new to programming)
Thank you for your attention!

```
import os, time, tkinter, urllib
from tkinter import *
from urllib.request import *
from urllib.error import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        v = StringVar()
        start_time = time.time()
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.label = Label(frame, textvariable=v).pack()
        if self.internet_on() == 1:
            v.set = "Internet is online"
            start_time = time.time()
        else:
            v.set = "Internet is offline!  Downtime: " + str(time.time() - start_time)


    def internet_on(self):
        try:
            response=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com.br',timeout=1)
            return True
        except urllib.error.URLError as err: pass
        return False            
top = tkinter.Tk()
app = App(top)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is `internet_on` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v.set` is a method, you are not supposed to write over it as -

```
v.set = "Internet is online"
```

You are supposed to call it and pass the string you want to write as argument -

```
v.set("Internet is online")
```

And

```
v.set("Internet is offline!  Downtime: " + str(time.time() - start_time))
```

---

As noted in the comments, you can also directly set the text value for the label , and then use `label.config()` to change the text. Example -

```
import os, time, tkinter, urllib
from tkinter import *
from urllib.request import *
from urllib.error import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        start_time = time.time()
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        if self.internet_on() == 1:
            self.label = Label(frame, text="Internet is online")
            self.label.pack()
            start_time = time.time()
        else:
            self.label = Label(frame, text="Internet is offline!  Downtime: " + str(time.time() - start_time))
            self.label.pack()


    def internet_on(self):
        try:
            response=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com.br',timeout=1)
            return True
        except urllib.error.URLError as err: pass
        return False            
top = tkinter.Tk()
app = App(top)

top.mainloop()
```

---

The best way to solve your requirement -

> In 'internet_on', periodically checking the internet status (change the text in the label). I already tried to use while with no sucess.

Would be to use `.after()` method of `Tk()` specifying a time in milliseconds (maye something like 5000 milliseconds or so , you can decide this) and specifying the iternet_on method as second argument and then using the `internet_on` method update the label. Example -

```
import os, time, tkinter, urllib
from tkinter import *
from urllib.request import *
from urllib.error import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        start_time = time.time()
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text="")
        self.label.pack()
        self.start_time = time.time()


    def internet_on(self):
        try:
            response=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com.br',timeout=1)
            self.label.config(text="Internet is online")
        except urllib.error.URLError as err:
            self.label.config(text="Internet is offline!  Downtime: " + str(time.time() - self.start_time))
        self.master.after(5000,self.internet_on)          
top = tkinter.Tk()
app = App(top)
top.after(5000,app.internet_on)
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to use StringVar.

Comment: Sorry, you don't need to do what?

Comment: Not for that particular usecase, but I am guessing he is learning to use tkinter, and for a bit more complex usecase (like maybe checking the same thing multiple times ad updating the label ) you would need a `StringVar()` , correct me if I am wrong, would there be a way to do that usecase (update the label later) without using StringVar?

Comment: You can update the label's (and in general widget's) _logical_ attributes using the `config` method (or its alias `configure`). `StringVar`
 is only necessary when you want to synchronise different widgets to have the same content, in this case the same text, IMO.

Comment: Ok, added an example for that as well. Personally , I think it would be cleaner to use `StringVar()` .

Comment: If there's no need for a `StringVar`, why create one? Also why not create the `Label` _after_ calling `internet_on()` and just putting the right `text` into it in the first place? Lastly, the `urllib.request.urlopen()` call is messed up in your current answer.

Comment: Thank you sir!! . But it still not updating. What can I do to make it refresh the label (change value of the label during runtime)?

Comment: When do you want to refresh the label?

Comment: In 'internet_on', periodically checking the internet status (change the text in the label).  I already tried to use while with no sucess.

Comment: Hmm , give me some time I will update it. In the meantime you can check out .after method , which is what you should be using for your case .

Comment: You're only checking once, in your `__init__` method.  To check periodically, you can use the tkinter `after` method.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method

Comment: Not update method , after method . Check out the link given in the above comment by saulspatz

Comment: Its not exactly similar, and theres not much difference that can be brought here. Anyway I didn't look at your solution at all, just noticed the similarity when you commented,

Comment: Thank you, It worked flawness. But I have a question: the .after() invokes .mainloop() or the .after() just invoke that same come over periodically?  ( I noticed that .mainloop() "freezes" the code in it invoke)

Comment: They are different things, `.after()` invokes the function after that many milliseconds, the invocation itself is handled by `root.mainloop()` .

Comment: mainloop() goes into an infinite loop where it keeps listening for events from the gui.

Comment: Why a widget text change do not call a event? (if it keeps listening)

Comment: You can configure to listen to events, but unless you configure in your code to listen to events, tkinter cannot magically deduce which method/function you want to call when a particular event is raised.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Sorry for my retard question. Thank you so much sir!!

Comment: Its not retarded at all :-) , sorry If I came off rude.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to do the updating in the method forgetting returning booleans and using `root.after`:

```
from tkinter import *
import  urllib.request
import urllib.error

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.label = Label(root, text="Starting.....")
        self.label.pack()
        self.internet_on()

    def internet_on(self):
        try:
            urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com.br', timeout=1)
            self.label.config(text="Internet is online")
            self.start_time = time.time()
        except urllib.error.URLError:
            self.label.config(text="Internet is offline!  Downtime: " + str(time.time() - self.start_time))
        root.after(1000, self.internet_on)

root = tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.pack()
```